# The use of "as" in "Wasting money as it does,..."

Tags: conjunctions

I came across the following sentence in a practice book:

*Wasting money as it does, I don't know how this business can succeed.*

When I looked it up in dictionaries, the closest use I found for **as** in this case is to show constrast, similar to **although**. For example: *Angry as he was, he couldn't help smiling.*

So, is the above sentence correct? It doesn't show contrast.

If it did, it would be:
*Wasting money as it does, the business still succeeds.*

Or can **as** be used that way to add information?

Thank you.

Comment: By most people's lights your first example *isn't* valid, because you've started with a [dangling participle](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_30.htm) (semantically, the subject of *wasting* should be *this business*, but syntactically it's ***I***). For the issue you're *really* asking about - No, there's nothing wrong with ***Wasting** money as it does, **this business** can't succeed [in my opinion].* Oh - and ***as*** here means ***in the [same] way*** (equating, not contrasting).

Comment: *I don't know how this business can succeed, wasting money the way it does*. (In the context, *as* means *in the way (that)*.)
It's a matter of construction.

Comment: Thank you both @FumbleFingers and Archa. Do you know what this construction is called? 
Is it a participle phrase?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don't see how the first example is invalid.  The referent of the participle phrase is easily and intuitively identified.  Though one can certainly construct examples that are awkward or ambiguous, it's entirely normal for phrases to not have the closest possible association with their referents.

Comment: In particular, since "it" is used in the participle phrase, one naturally skips over "I" as a possible referent.  "Wasting", of course, is tied to "it", not anything in the rest of the sentence, and it is "it" that refers to "this business".

Comment: @Hot Licks: I never suggested anyone would have a problem *understanding* OP's text - in fact, I specifically contrasted the *semantics* (the meaning we naturally assume) with the *syntax*. But undoubtedly it *is* a classic example of a dangling participle (structurally, it's identical to the example ***Flying** south for the winter, **I** saw a huge flock of swallows,* as given in my link). Most people who know of such things would surely agree that it's an "error" - in this context, you just happen not to be included in what I refer to as "most people".

Comment: No, they are quite different.  "wasting" is connected with/qualified by "it".  And the reference of "it" cannot be reasonably misconstrued.  If the sentence were simply "Wasting money, I don't know how this business can succeed" then that would be a different situation.

Comment: Yes, the use of "as" is proper. In this sentence, "as" simply means "like" (i.e., "Wasting money like it does, I don't know how this business can succeed."). It should be noted, however, that this sentence is mismodified. @FumbleFingers is right. The absolute phrase "wasting time as it does" is a dangling participle.  It needs to refer to the subject, but the subject "I" isn't wasting time—the "business" is.  So the sentence needs to be reworded to make "business" the subject, or the introductory phrase needs to be changed so that it doesn't improperly modify the main clause's subject-verb.

Comment: What @Benjamin said. Just because the pronoun ***it*** in OP's example "forward references" ***this business*** doesn't alter the fact that this isn't the "subject" of the dangling participle ***wasting***. This might be more obvious if we retain that pronoun with slightly different phrasing: *Wasting **its** money like that, I don't know how this business can succeed*.

Answer (score 1):

*The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fourth edition (2000) identifies two relevant meanings of the word as when it is used as a conjunction:

> **as** ... *conj.* ... **2.** In the same manner or way that: *Think as I think*. ... **6.** Though: *Great as the author was, he proved a bad model*.

The first example—

> Wasting money as it does, I don't know how this business can succeed.

—amounts to saying

> I don't know how this business can succeed, wasting money as it does.

where *it* refers to "this business." The comparison is therefore reflexive—in effect, "this business, wasting money in the manner or way that this business does..." The meaning of *as* in the original wording is thus the meaning given as definition 2 of *AHDEL* above, except that the word "same" is unnecessary in the substitution of the definition for the original word *as* because a thing is necessarily the same as itself.

The second example—

> Angry as he was, he couldn't help smiling.

—clearly uses *as* in the sense of "though"—*AHDEL*'s sixth definition above.

Comment: I think the OP is also incorrectly taking *as* to have 3 arguments: "wasting money", "it does", and "I don't know how this business can succeed", hence their suggestion of *as* marking contrast. Perhaps the idea of contrast comes from sentences like "As steady as it is, I won't trust my weight to it.", with the initial *as* ellipsed.